# How to add custom text in the price of specific variable selected - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We are currently developing a website for a client who wants to have 2 options for the products they are selling - 1st option should be displaying the price for only 1 packet of coffee, and the next option should be showing the price for a full stack of packets. Depending on the product, the stack can consist of 6, 8, 10 or 12 packets. For this reason we have created multiple variable attributes and have set 2 options that the clients can choose from for each product - 1st one is for 1 packet and the 2nd one is for a stack. The client however wants a custom text to appear when the customer selects the stack option, notifying that there will be a 10% discount of the overall amount. We don't want to set the stack variable on sale, as it sets the overall product on sale, which is not our idea. Currently we are using the following code to add the text after the price:

```
//Custom text
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'custom_variation_price_addition', 10, 3 );
function custom_variation_price_addition( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    $price  = wc_get_price_to_display( $variation );
    $suffix = sprintf( __("You're saving 10%") );

    $data['price_html'] .= '<span class="4xcb"> ' . $suffix . '</span>';

    return $data;
}
```

Is there a way we can target all variable attributes, apart from the 1 packet option, to pull up this text? We saw another topic where it was suggested to include all of the variable IDs we want the text to be displayed on, however this is not ideal, as we have a lot of products that have 2 options to choose from.

Link to the website:

https://unionvending.bg/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Maybe `$variation->get_variation_attributes();` then test if one...